# Microsoft C/C++ linker optimization failing to discard unused code/data

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker

I'm writing a C++ library that contains different compression algorithms, and allows the user to specify a particular one that is then used whenever the user calls Compress()/Uncompress().

**Problem:** Some of the external libraries I'm using (such as zlib) are strictly C, and for some reason the linker does NOT optimize out all of the zlib functions and data like you'd expect.

**Example:** If the user selects that he wishes to use bzip, there are no code paths to zlib, and thus, no zlib code should be linked/included in the final binary. In fact, my C++ class that wraps zlib is even discarded by the linker when viewing the /VERBOSE linker output or the generated .map file. HOWEVER, about 30KB of zlib code is STILL included in the binary.

**Test to reproduce:** A simple console application with a main that returns 0, but contains the zlib source file in the Visual Studio project will also add the additional ~30KB of code. There is obviously no code path at all that calls any of the zlib functions, so WHY is it still included in the executable?
Zlib symbols from map file:

```
0001:00000000       _adler32                   00401000 f   adler32.obj
0001:00002470       __tr_stored_block          00403470 f   trees.obj
0001:00002510       __tr_flush_block           00403510 f   trees.obj
...
0002:00001cc0       _z_errmsg                  0040bcc0     zutil.obj
0002:00002330       __dist_code                0040c330     trees.obj
0002:00002530       __length_code              0040c530     trees.obj
0002:00002720       _inflate_copyright         0040c720     inftrees.obj
0002:000039a0       _deflate_copyright         0040d9a0     deflate.obj
0002:00005a68       ??_C@_00CNPNBAHC@?$AA@     0040fa68     gzlib.obj
0002:00005a6c       ??_C@_0BF@CJFPCCEG@incompatible?5version?$AA@ 0040fa6c     zutil.obj
0002:00005a84       ??_C@_0N@DFPGLBGC@buffer?5error?$AA@ 0040fa84     zutil.obj
0002:00005a94       ??_C@_0BE@OGGJBMCE@insufficient?5memory?$AA@ 0040fa94     zutil.obj
0002:00005aa8       ??_C@_0L@HAHMBNLP@data?5error?$AA@ 0040faa8     zutil.obj
0002:00005ab4       ??_C@_0N@MKKNPMJD@stream?5error?$AA@ 0040fab4     zutil.obj
0002:00005ac4       ??_C@_0L@KIJFAKBJ@file?5error?$AA@ 0040fac4     zutil.obj
0002:00005ad0       ??_C@_0L@FNAOCBOG@stream?5end?$AA@ 0040fad0     zutil.obj
0002:00005adc       ??_C@_0BA@MOKMMFOD@need?5dictionary?$AA@ 0040fadc     zutil.obj
...
0001:00000270       _crc32_little              00401270 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00000530       _flush_pending             00401530 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00000580       _longest_match             00401580 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:000006e0       _fill_window               004016e0 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00000920       _deflate_stored            00401920 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00000c10       _deflate_fast              00401c10 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001000       _deflate_slow              00402000 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001510       _init_block                00402510 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001590       _pqdownheap                00402590 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001670       _gen_bitlen                00402670 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001870       _gen_codes                 00402870 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:000018f0       _build_tree                004028f0 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001af0       _scan_tree                 00402af0 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00001bd0       _send_tree                 00402bd0 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00002150       _build_bl_tree             00403150 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00002220       _send_all_trees            00403220 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00002760       _compress_block            00403760 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00002b40       _detect_data_type          00403b40 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00002bb0       _bi_flush                  00403bb0 f    CIL library: CIL module
0001:00002c30       _copy_block                00403c30 f    CIL library: CIL module
```

**Speculation/Help Requested:** I'm not a linker expert, but it appears that the main culprit is data in the form of const arrays. For example, all the CIL modules and a few of the other functions are brought in because of a single array table that is defined on line 131 in zlib's deflate.c:

```
local const config configuration_table[10] = {
/*      good lazy nice chain */
/* 0 */ {0,    0,  0,    0, deflate_stored},  /* store only */
/* 1 */ {4,    4,  8,    4, deflate_fast}, /* max speed, no lazy matches */
/* 2 */ {4,    5, 16,    8, deflate_fast},
/* 3 */ {4,    6, 32,   32, deflate_fast},

/* 4 */ {4,    4, 16,   16, deflate_slow},  /* lazy matches */
/* 5 */ {8,   16, 32,   32, deflate_slow},
/* 6 */ {8,   16, 128, 128, deflate_slow},
/* 7 */ {8,   32, 128, 256, deflate_slow},
/* 8 */ {32, 128, 258, 1024, deflate_slow},
/* 9 */ {32, 258, 258, 4096, deflate_slow}}; /* max compression */
```

The linker thus sees the references to functions, and links all of them along too.

Does anyone know WHY this is? Would my library work better if I rebuilt zlib and the other associated libraries as C++? Does there exist a solution for me to employ for my library to successfully link against ONLY the required library, and NOT pull along all the other compression libraries as well?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: do you enable optimization?

Comment: Optimization is enabled, both /Gy in the c/c++ compiler code generation as well as the linker /OPT:REF and /OPT:ICF.

Comment: That table contains pointers to functions.  If that table (or the object in which it is defined) is used, then all of those functions are also used because their addresses are taken.

Comment: The problem is the sole function in this test project is:

#include <Windows.h>

int wmain( int argc, wchar_t* argv[] )
{
    return 0;
}

.... So there are absolutely zero references to this table or any zlib functions at all. The table is clearly used within zlib itself, but my main source file does not reference anything zlib.

Comment: have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to fixed it by adding **/Gw** compiler switch. It will remove unused global data from the final executable. More information available here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/09/11/introducing-gw-compiler-switch/